# How to display int as a TimeSpan in string.Format?

Tags: c#, formatting, timespan, string.format

I have the following code:

```cs
int sec = 62;
string str = string.Format("Time: {0:xxx}", sec);
```

What should I type in the place of `xxx` if I want an output like this: `Time: 00:01:02`?

I know I can type:

```cs
string.Format("Time: {0:xxx}", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec));
```

or similar but the only part I can change is the `xxx` part.

Any ideas?

Comment: Giving restrictions without reasons is frowned upon (at least by me). Why can't you change more than just the `xxx` part? I fear there is no solution unless you can actually write code and not just change the formatting... Good luck!

Comment: I draw a chart and assigning points to it. The points represent seconds. The chart is drawn by using this int values (seconds) but I want it to display the point values not as seconds but in a form of xx:yy:zz. But the only part that I can change is a string formatting the value being displayed. So the string `"Time: {0:xxx}"` is the one I can change, the variable named by me as `sec` is the one being passed by the chart control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the format string cannot change the type of its arguments there is no other option than the one you cannot use.

After all, `int` is a type that contains numbers (fundamentally, at least), not time spans and thus why would an `int` be formattable as a time span?

Comment: Well, actually TimeSpan is formattable, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx but this is not the point here.

Comment: Aaah, one new thing in .NET 4 I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like `String.Format("Time: {0}", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec).ToString("c");`

The exact format of the `ToString` argument can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx